# bundle external jar into dependancies for output jar file

Tags: gradle

I have the following `build.gradle` file. One of my dependences is `json-simple`. However,
when I create my jar `HttpSnapClient` that is not included in the jar file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'         
apply plugin: 'application'  
apply plugin: 'groovy'       

mainClassName = 'com.sunsystem.HttpSnapClient.SnapClient'

repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1"
   testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.3.3"
   testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
}

jar {
    baseName = 'HttpSnapclient'
    version ='1.0.0'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

I would like to bundle the `json-simple.jar` into my `HttpSnapClient.jar` so my application that will use this `HttpSnapClient.jar` will already have `json-simple.jar` included.

when I run the following command jar tvf HttpSnapclient-1.0.0.jar

```
     0 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 META-INF/
    25 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   294 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 WebServiceResponseCodes.class
     0 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 com/
     0 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 com/sunsystem/
     0 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 com/sunsystem/HttpSnapClient/
  5965 Mon Jun 30 14:37:56 ICT 2014 com/sunsystem/HttpSnapClient/SnapClient.class
```

There is no json-simple included, so any application that uses this HttpSnapClient will fail as its looking for the json-simple that has not been included.

When I run I get the following: `gradle dependencies`

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
     \--- junit:junit:4.10
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1
     \--- junit:junit:4.10
          \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are running **gradle build** instead of **gradle distZip** or **gradle distTar** which bundles everything into either a zip og tar. Might be you are more interested in the solution @Opal is suggesting though. Application plugin will create a distribution with a bin folder for startupscripts and a lib for all your jars.

Comment: Yes, I am running gradle build. However, I don't want to bundle everything into a tar archive. What I am looking to do is end up with a single jar. As I will have many external jar's (currently I just have json-simple). And I want to bundle all of them into a single jar, which in my case will be called HttpSnapclient.jar. Thanks.

Comment: Guessed so :) Some alternatives to consider then would be the mentioned Fat Jar as well as https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar or manipulating the war/jar task like this one: https://github.com/jhannes/java-ee-turnkey/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will check that out first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

[Fat Jar](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin/) is a plugin You're probably looking for. By default dependencies are not included into jar file.